# Can call Activity from JavascriptInterface in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, android-activity, cordova

I am new to phonegap and my project, I need to call an activity from
the javascript in the html page, is it possible?

```
   


    public void capturePhoto() {
            JavascriptInterface.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {              
                   try{
                        Intent i = new Intent(JavascriptInterface.this, GetPicture.class);                  
                        startActivity(i);
                   }catch(Exception e){
                       Toast.makeText(mContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }

               }
            });
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with web programming on android or with the javascript interfaces, so I don't know if it's possible to launch an arbitrary intent with those.

However, I assume that you have some way to simply open a link. And if you find out that it's not possible to launch an activity otherwise, you can still get something working, using a custom URI scheme.

Basically, the idea is that you add an intent filter to the activity that you want to launch that registers a custom URI scheme for that activity. And then when you try to open a link using that scheme, Android will map that to an android.intent.action.VIEW intent for your activity.

For example, If you have the following in the intent filter for the activity that you want to launch:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="penroser"/>
</intent-filter>
```

You could then launch a URL like `penroser:BLAH`, and it should actually launch your activity.

However, the above assumes that you are able to add an intent filter to the activity that you want to launch. However, if you want to launch a more general intent, or launch an activity that you don't control, it makes things a bit more complicated.

In this case, you could define a "spring-board" activity, whose purpose is to receive the custom URI intents, and then decode some intent information using some format that you define, and then launch an intent based on that decoded information.

For example, let's say that you register the custom URI scheme `launchactivity:`, and then you could launch a link like: `launchactivity://activity?component=com.example.MyActivity`, and then have some parsing logic in the spring-board Activity that parses out the component name from the URI and launches an intent for that component.

Depending on exactly what you needed, you should be able to pass any intent data you need in a `launchactivity:` URL

Comment: I use ASP.NET MVC to create website and I want to pass parameters to phonegap program, and I use the method: shouldoverrideurlloading to load Phonegap's activity. I use the link: camera:param1=value1&&param2=value2 to pass parameter.

Comment: Was there a question in that comment somewhere? :)